# Custom actions on Keystone JS 6

Tags: typescript, keystonejs

I try to implement add custom actions for duplicate content (for example Product). Imagine you have a product and want to create new but very similar and you want just click Clone or Duplicate button to create a similar product and start to edit over this new. Where and how I can add this button?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a `virtual` field type which does not return a value but has `custom view`. With this view you can add custom actions.

ideally you would want this in a button somewhere other than editor area, but that is not possible with current release. They say it is in roadmap but no much details available publicly.

code sandbox links for
virtual field: https://githubbox.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/virtual-field
custom field view: https://githubbox.com/keystonejs/keystone/tree/main/examples/custom-field-view